# Double render in React - is this a problem?

Tags: reactjs

I have Parent component which renders a Child component, and a Child component have  method that updates Parent state. Now I need to write additional method that changes other part of Parent state and call previous method after that. Eventually I have two methods that updating state twice in a row which leads to re-rendering Parent component twice too:

```
handleReset() {
    this.props.onReset(this.props.rule)
    this.handleChange()
}

handleChange() {
    this.props.buttonClick(this.props.rule, !this.props.oldStateVal)
}
```

Is this a problem or anti-pattern? I have read somewhere that React might combine few `setState` calls in a single one in order to improve performance but it doesn't happening.

Comment: It's not a `setState` calls, you making `callBack` calls

Comment: To fix it, you should pass a function which accepts a function.